# What is an 'Invincibility Frame'?

Tags: terminology

I've seen people talking about invincibility frames or i-frames, for example, Dark Souls 2. What are they and what do they do?

Comment: Please provide a little more context. What game/genre are you hearing the term used in?

Comment: I'd assume this is in relation to fighting games, that's the genre that typically refers to things as 'frames'.

Comment: @TZHX yes, when I saw that the first thing that popped into my head is SF4.

Comment: @TZHX invincibility frames aren't just for fighters, standard mechanic in platformers and shmups. Invincibility frames can save your life in Mega Man

Comment: @PrinnyBrocka Indeed. That's why I said 'assume', and 'typically', not 'most certainly is' and 'exclusively'.

Comment: This is actually a self-answer question. And I hope someone would provide a clearer, better answer than me. Because I don't think my answer is good enough

Comment: @PrinnyBrocka Can you provide some examples? I am not judging nor being sarcasm, just curious to see because I've never beat any Rockman games.

Comment: @008 Most platformers have this. Heck, even Mario games have it. If you can touch an enemy and don't immediately die (because you took damage again on every subsequent frame), the game has *some* form of invincibility frames that trigger when you take damage. It's essentially a gameplay necessity for any game where you don't always die in a single hit.

Comment: In Mega Man a common trick is to get hit by a weak enemy shot, then run on spikes that are normally instakill. Some games even have equipables that extend invincibility frames. You can also just take a hit to clip through an enemy in many platformers if you think contact damage will be lower than damage you take fighting it. In Mega Man bosses have invincibility frames too to prevent rapid fire attacks from being over powered and to change the flow of battle.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on [Smashpedia](http://supersmashbros.wikia.com/wiki/Invincibility_frame), invincibility frames are the period of time (measured in frames) during which a character cannot be damaged.

During the invincibility frames, most damage cannot be dealt to the character, and most invincibility will render the player invulnerable to disable as well.

Invincibility frame can be applied to game for skillful playing, like rolling/dodging,  and special skills/items. It could also be added to prevent instant death upon respawning. Here are some examples:

- Dark Souls: Rolling
- Monster Hunter: Rolling
- Bastion: Rolling
- Guild Wars 2: Rolling
- DotA 2: Certain skills
- League of Legends: Certain skills and items
- Diablo 3: Certain skills
- Ikaruga: Respawning
- Gradius: Respawning

Comment: Apparently, rolling is the key to immortality.

Comment: @Zibbobz you've never played witcher 2 have you :P  I probably rolled around more (distance wise) than actual walking.

Comment: Doesn't backstabbing / riposte grant invincibility in Dark Souls 2?